# Firebase deployment issue with Angular node_modules

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to deploy my Angular app to Firebase, and I keep getting this error and it is not clear what is the specific module that is causing this on building application

```
[debug] [2023-05-06T12:09:25.788Z] Error
    at scheduleTarget (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/angular/index.js:51:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async build (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/angular/index.js:64:9)
    at async prepareFrameworks (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js:193:108)
    at async deploy (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:55:13)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

This is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "ichess",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "chess.js": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ngx-chess-board": "^2.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
}
```

I was expecting the deployment to complete without issues.

Comment: Bit confused, what are you deploying? If it’s an angular app build it locally (or as part of a cd pipeline like GitHub actions) and then Firebase is just serving the html, js, css files. No node_modules needed

Comment: @AndrewAllen I tried to serve it locally and it is working using command -> firebase serve
however if i deployed it using -> firebase deploy it gave me this error

Comment: @AndrewAllen I got your idea and created dist locally using ng build --aot then made firebase only deploy destination which worked thanks !

Comment: Cool, would love to see what you’ve built if you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment issue it usually happens for not selecting the correct directory

```
ng build
```

`firebase init` <--- (after selecting Hosting and the project associate)

`dist/YOUR-APP-NAME` <--- change YOUR-APP-NAME by the content in your local dist

For next changes in your app;

```
ng build

firebase deploy
```